Magento 2.4.6 with Amasty Improved Layered Navigation issue
I'm currently running a Magento 2.4.6 website with Porto Theme, Amasty Improved Layered Navigation and Wyomind Mass Product Import extensions.
I currently have products that include a couple of attributes that refer to the products they work with like "compatible manufacturer" and "compatible model".
These attributes are used in the layered navigation filters so you can select the compatible manufacturer first and then the choice of compatible models can be filtered to show the right product(s).
It all works fine.
Today I imported 40 more of these products using the mass product import extension and that completed fine with the products showing in stock, visible in the catalog and via the search bar, with the two attributes populated and showing on the frontend product page.
Only issue is that in the layered navigation, when I filter the compatible manufacturer, the "compatible model" for the new products doesn't show up as an option even when there is a product available for it.
I have tried to delete the new "compatible model" options in the attribute settings and add them again manually and that didn't help.
I've tried adding a new product manually with a new attribute option manually and that didn't work either.
I have re-indexed, cleared the cache, deleted the cache in the var folder, nothing has helped.
It's like the layered navigation doesn't see that the attribute option has products using it so it doesn't show the option in the filters. When I change it to "Filterable (no results)" the new options show up but are not selectable.
Has anybody experienced something similar and solved it? Am I missing something?
